# Search function return unwanted results in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have made search function which looks like is working instead one `where` clause. I want in the results to not show items which aren't published yet.

So if item has `published = 0` in database should not be shown on page even if is met the search conditions.

This is my function

```
public function search(Request $request)
{

    $searchText = strip_tags($request['q']);
    $seachLocation = strip_tags($request['l']);


    $columns =['alias','description'];

    $query = Item::select('*');

    $query->where( 'title', 'like', '%'.$searchText.'%');
    $query->where('published', 1);
    foreach( $columns as $column) {
        $query->orWhere( $column, 'like', '%'.$searchText.'%', '%'.$seachLocation.'%');
    }

    $query->orWhereHas('category',function( $query ) use (  $searchText ) {
        $query->where('title', 'like', '%'.$searchText.'%' );
    });

    $query->orWhereHas('country',function( $query ) use (  $searchText ) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$searchText.'%' );
    });

    $items = $query->paginate(5);
    $searchQuery = $searchText;
    $searchQueryLoc = $seachLocation;


    return view('search', compact('items','searchQuery','seachLocation'));
}
```

What I've added is

```
$query->where('published', 1);
```

which should carry this condition but I still see unpublished items on page. Why is that?

toSql return

```
select * from `items` where `title` like ? and `published` = ? and (`alias` like ? or `description` like ?) or exists (select * from `categories` where `items`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id` and `title` like ?) or exists (select * from `countries` where `items`.`country_id` = `countries`.`id` and `name` like ?) limit 5 offset 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print out the SQL and you'll see why.  SQL groups conditions around the OR which means `condition 1` OR `condition 2 AND condition 3` are evaluated separately.

This is why you nest conditions with parentheses so condition 3 is always evaluated:

`(condition 1 OR condition 2) AND condition 3`

The same goes for Laravel, the way you nest is with callbacks:

```
$query->where(function($q) use ($columns, $searchText, $seachLocation) {
     foreach( $columns as $column) {
         $q->orWhere( $column, 'like', '%'.$searchText.'%', '%'.$seachLocation.'%');
     }
}
```

You can always use `$query->toSql()` to see a representation of the generated SQL.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this but still see all results. I've added the sql in question

Comment: You still have the other or conditions in place.

Comment: Yes, because they're looking in other tables.

Comment: Well... I already answered your question on why it's happening, I think you need to take it from here...  but I'll give you a hint... group the complete condition under the callback.