# Laravel where('user_id') seems completely ignored

Tags: laravel

I have a problem where `user_id` seems completely ignored by Laravels Eloquent ORM.

**Pigeons** Table
`id  user_id  name  father_id  mother_id  ringnumber
gender  color  created_at  updated_at  landcode`
(these are my columns (if someone knows how to format this better, let me know))

I have a search from which routes a search parameter `q` to my SearchController.php in which this function lives:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Pigeon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $q = Input::get('query');

        $userId = Auth::user()->id;

        $pigeons = Pigeon::where([
                ['user_id', '=', $userId],
                ['name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%']
            ])
            ->orWhere('ringnumber','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
            ->sortable()
            ->paginate(15);
        dd($pigeons);

        return view('backend.pigeon.pigeonlist')->with('pigeons', $pigeons);
    }
}
```

For some reason this Eloquent query builder completely seems to ignore `'user_id', '=', $userId` and this is an important part because I only want to search for pigeons for the current logged in user.

Below is a result of such a query, the problem is that there are pigeons with all kinds of `user_id` and not only the one user that searched for them.

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#259 ▼
    #total: 150
    #lastPage: 10
    #items: Collection {#267 ▼
      #items: array:15 [▼
        0 => Pigeon {#268 ▶}
        1 => Pigeon {#269 ▶}
        2 => Pigeon {#270 ▶}
        3 => Pigeon {#271 ▶}
        4 => Pigeon {#272 ▶}
        5 => Pigeon {#273 ▶}
        6 => Pigeon {#274 ▶}
        7 => Pigeon {#275 ▶}
        8 => Pigeon {#276 ▶}
        9 => Pigeon {#277 ▶}
        10 => Pigeon {#278 ▶}
        11 => Pigeon {#279 ▶}
        12 => Pigeon {#280 ▶}
        13 => Pigeon {#281 ▶}
        14 => Pigeon {#282 ▶}
      ]
    }
    #perPage: 15
    #currentPage: 1
    #path: "http://mywebsite.test/pigeon/search"
    #query: []
    #fragment: null
    #pageName: "page"
    +onEachSide: 3
  }
```

Small note, I got some of my information from here: [How to create multiple where clause query using Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent)

Problem solved:
First I had an orWhere which overruled the where so that was pretty stupid of me.
Second my real problem was that I was trying to get only records for the current logged in user that works via this code:

```
$pigeons = Pigeon::where('user_id', \Auth::id())
                ->where(function($query) use ($q) {
                    $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $q .'%');
                })
                ->sortable()
                ->paginate(15);
```

Comment: What's in `ringnumber`? Is that specific to a user too?

Comment: No sir, ringnumber is not specific to user, it's specific to a pigeon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search function return unwanted results in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46830485/search-function-return-unwanted-results-in-laravel)

Comment: The problem happens when you use `->orWhere` you say either the one above is true, or this is true.

Comment: Yes that's correct, the orWhere was overruling the where, which was causing it to neglate the user_id

Comment: @ArneDB - Then, you are receiving all of the results due to that `orWhere` of course.

Comment: Thanks guys. I feel stupid for overlooking this. Glad we could figure this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the right behavior since you are adding an `orWhere` clause after the where.

This will result in a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE (user_id = xxx) OR (some condition that results true)
```

Since `false OR true` is equal to `true`, the first clause is being ignored (because the second is true)

Comment: Indeed, answer was already given, but since this is the only one I can accept, I'll accep this correct answer! Thanks for taking the time to write it out like this!